# How to change location permission message for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, core-location

I'm learning iOS development and faced strange problem. To get user permission for using location in `viewController` I'm defining location manager and requesting `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`.

Like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let lm = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lm.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Then, in plist I'm setting proper text for permission dialog, like this:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location</string>
```

Everything works fine till I'm trying to change text for permission dialog. After changing it in plist I'm recompiling it but nothing changes in the app, I'm receiving dialog with old text. So my question - how can I change it?
P.S. Xcode 10.3 & iOS 12.4

Comment: Normally it the change reflects immediately. But in you case, you can try deleting the app and running again. Perhaps clearing derived data.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ViewController.swift file and add the following line to import the CoreLocation framework.

```
import CoreLocation
```

Conform the ViewController class to the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol. Change the class declaration line to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
Add the following property

let locationMgr = CLLocationManager()
```

The  CLLocationManager is the object that will give you the GPS coordinates. Next, implement the getLocation(_:) method.

```
@IBAction func getLocation(_ sender: Any) {
    // 1
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    switch status {
        // 1
    case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            return

        // 2
    case .denied, .restricted:
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Location Services disabled", message: "Please enable Location Services in Settings", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        break

    }

    // 4
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

The authorizationStatus returns the current authorisation status.

The when in use authorisation get location updates while the app is in the foreground

When location services is disabled, the user will be shown an alert

Send location updates to the delegate, which is the View Controller.

Next, implement the CLLocationManager delegate methods.

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let currentLocation = locations.last {
        print("Current location: \(currentLocation)")
    }
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
```

The current location is printed to the console.

An Error is generated and displayed when the location can't get updated.

To enable the permissions for location updates while the app is running a special key is needed. Open info.plist. Right-click and select Add Row. Enter the following Values.

```
In Info.plist
<key>NSLocationWhenInUse</key>
<string>This app needs access to your Location</string>
```

Build and Run the project, When the app ask for permission

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found where problem was. But firs things first. If you are trying to localize your app - read carefully what xcode asks you. In my case it was deleting Info.plist file from root directory when I tried to localize it, then (obviously) xcode informed me that it can't make a build because of it can't find Info.plist file (which was deleted from root directory).

**Solution**

1. Move Info.plist from Base.lproj directory;
2. Make as [written](https://flowinho.com/2019/07/17/localize-privacy-settings-in-xcode10.html) in this article;
3. Keys in strings file should be exactly as they are named in system. This won't work:

"SomKey" = "We need you location";

But this would:

"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "We need you location";